# Android dropbox api needs re-authentication

Tags: android, authentication, dropbox

In my application, i use dropbox api to keep some files, it's ok. After authentication i close the app and re-launch app. It needs re-authentication each time i opened the application.I want the application to remember my session.

Answer (score 1):

[Dropbox tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android#authenticating) suggest storing the authentication token as SharedPreferences, so you could restore it later.

You can see an example application in dropbox SDK located in `\dropbox-android-sdk-1.6\examples\DBRoulette`.

In the activity's `onCreate()` method check if preference is stored and if it is then instean of calling authentication window use `session.setOAuth2AccessToken(RESTORED_TOKEN);`

Sample code to do this:

```
public void onCreate() {
    AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
    AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys, ACCESS_TYPE);
    mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

    String token = getTokenFromPreferences();
    if (token != null) {
        session.setOAuth2AccessToken(token);
    } else {
        mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(MyActivity.this);
    }
}
```